# I have a WPF 3d object and the textblock text is getting displayed in reverse direction. Why?

Tags: wpf

[image]I have the following code in my app amd the text block is displaying in reverse direction. How to display the text normally

```
<GeometryModel3D x:Name="Front">
    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
        <DiffuseMaterial>
            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                <VisualBrush>
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="10pt" Margin="2">Hello, from the Front!</TextBlock>
                            <Button Margin="2">A Button</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
        </DiffuseMaterial>
    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
        <MeshGeometry3D Positions="1,1,1 -1,1,1 -1,-1,1 1,-1,1"
            TextureCoordinates="1,1 0,1 0,0 1,0"
            TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3"/>
    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
</GeometryModel3D>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is purely a question of TextureCoordinates, you just have to completely mirror them, change all 1 with 0 and all 0 with 1:

```
TextureCoordinates="0,0 1,0 1,1 0,1"
```

extended answer:
Texture coordinates are defined in the same order than the vertices (Positions) so each vertex holds a UV (xy in texture space) to say what pixel will be mapped into that vertex. With the classic difference from standard informatics graphics that 0,0 yield the bottom left and not the top left (of the texture image). And the values in between vertices (on the surface) are interpolated by the rasterizer.

Comment: could be that the "front" is not the geometry where is the texture. (that is if the suggested modification above didnt change one thing). Because the front is just a quad, this cube is made of 6 quads, or at least 3 if it is not intended to be rotated or viewed from the back. Next step : make your brain work to fiddle with the texture coordinates.